# Playing a video file from a url in Swift 4/Xcode 9: AVF context unavailable for sharedAudioPresentationContext

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I am trying to implement an AVPlayer which loads and plays a video from a url. This is placed within a function that is called by a button. Here is my current code:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class MovieDetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func playTrailer(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let videoURL = URL(string: "http://caribbeancinemas.com/img/trailers/6134.mp4") else {
            return
        }

        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player

        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app on the simulator the video actually plays but there are two issues happening:

1. I get the following error message in the console:

   > 2018-03-31 16:49:53.389148-0400 MoviesApp[18928:3137301] [MediaRemote] [AVOutputContext] WARNING: AVF context unavailable for sharedAudioPresentationContext
   >   2018-03-31 16:49:53.497987-0400 MoviesApp[18928:3137301] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
   >   2018-03-31 16:49:53.498937-0400 MoviesApp[18928:3137301] [framework] CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'
   >   2018-03-31 16:49:53.857871-0400 MoviesApp[18928:3138058] Task <223C4724-B3B5-4EBE-9AE0-5BA3C30B37C6>.<2> finished with error - code: -999
   >   2018-03-31 16:49:55.365686-0400 MoviesApp[18928:3138196] Task <95E91605-9B52-4212-97B3-47E73CE21B8B>.<1> finished with error - code: -999
2. The video player doesn't starts playing the video right away (buffering) but it seems to wait until it downloads the entire video before playing.

I have looked here for a solution to this but haven't found one yet so any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem?  I'm getting the same error.

Comment: No, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func playTrailer(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let videoURL = URL(string: "http://caribbeancinemas.com/img/trailers/6134.mp4") else {
            return
        }

        let videoAsset = AVURLAsset(url: videoURL! as URL)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: videoAsset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player

        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but got the same results. It also told me to remove the force unwrap and cast "! as URL". Could you elaborate on your answer and why AVURLAsset and AVPlayerItem are needed? Thanks.

Comment: To avoid the issue: Invalid asset name supplied: '(null)'